# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<model1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<model2>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I have created two tables based on the following classes  in SQL databse,my first table is(Clients):

```
public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
public double? Name { get; set; } = default!;
public string? FamilyName { get; set; } = default!;
public List<Addresses> ClientAddress { get; set; } = default!;
```

and my second table is Addresses :

```
public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
public string Address { get; set; } = default!;
```

i found this approach on internet!now the problem is i get Clients model from UI and want to store it how should i do it in linq?i get error :

```
public Task<bool> StoreModel(Clients client)
{
     var listtostore = new ClientsEntity()
       {
           Name = client.Name,
           FamilyName = client.FamilyName,
           ClientAddress =client.ClientAddress//i get conversion error here
       }
}
```

My clientsEnity is:

```
 [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = default!;
    public double? Name { get; set; } = default!;
    public string? FamilyName { get; set; } = default!;
    public List<Addresses> ClientAddress { get; set; } = default!;
```

Comment: Please show `ClientsEntity` class

Comment: @OneCricketeer updated my question

Comment: Why do you effectively have two classes that are the exact same? `Clients` and `ClientsEntity`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Clients is a model and ClientsEntity is the Enitity i have built my table in the database based on it,when i get data from UI i get it in my Model and stored in the DB using Entity

Comment: But if both hold the exact same information, then you dont really need to copy information between the two.

Comment: Do not name classes in the plural. Name properties that are collections in the plural

Comment: My guess would be that "Addresses" in the Client class (DTO) is a different type than the "Addresses" in ClientEntity (Entity)  Your naming convention is VERY confusing, and probably not very consistent. In any case if you're going through the trouble of using ViewModels/DTOs alongside your entities you should not be mixing Entity references (Addresses) between entity and DTO. Chances are your Entity DTO has an Address DTO that confusingly has the same class name.

Answer (score 0):

ClientAddress is a list

initialize them firt and try again

```
listtostore.ClientAddress = new List<Addresses>();

foreach(var item in client.ClientAddress)
{
listtostore.ClientAddress.Add(item)
}
```

Comment: is it the best approach?